# URL connection with proxy not working but curl is working for intranet

Tags: java, networking

I am trying to access the internet and intranet site using the same generic code.  When using a proxy, my internet calls are working fine but intranet calls are failing. I tried curl command it works fine for intranet as well.

Here is my code snippet which is very generic.

```
URL url = new URL(targetURL);
if (proxy != null) {
    inputStream = url.openConnection(proxy).getInputStream();
} else {
    inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow anand. Please tell use what "not" working does mean. Are there any exceptions you can provide? It has hard from your question and code to find out what the problem is and what the expected behaviour is.

Comment: I am not able to call intranet website from java with proxy details.   Proxy information is getting passed to URL connection correctly.  I tried the same website with proxy using curl command and I got no issue.

Comment: `openConnection` could throw `IOException`. Does it in your case? And can you provide the code you use to setup your `proxy`?

Comment: proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(PROXY.IP, PROXY.PORT));

Comment: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied (connect failed)

Comment: does your proxy require authentication with a username and password? If so, you need to provide those credentials as well.

Comment: No there is no permission required. However, when I am trying to the same URL from Linux using curl it is working fine. Must be some JVM options I am missing.